# How to search for 2-9 digits inside a string with regexp?

Tags: python, regex, string, int

```
for item in range(len(items)):
    pi = re.compile(items[item], re.IGNORECASE)
    mi = pi.search('\d+')
    if mi:
        print('löydettiin asiakasnumero, siirretään alkuun')
        os.rename(folders[item], mi.group()+items[item].strip('0123456789'))
        rename += 1
    else:
```

This is what I have so far, but even this pattern is not giving me matches (the inputs are something like example co 23425345)

Comment: You are looking for the item in the string `\d+`. I'm not sure that's what you want to do (probably the opposite). Note that `pi.search(str)` looks for the regular expression `pi` in the string `str`.

Comment: Well isn't that embarrassing. Tunnel vision, I have the search term and input swapped. Thanks man!

Comment: Actually I think the interface is confusing: `str.find(x)` finds `x` in `str`. `regx.search(x)` looks for `regx` in `x`. So there is some inconsistency here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, use `\d{2,9}` to match numbers with 2-9 digits.

Comment: This was the best answer. I know the pattern, that was easy, I just didn't notice I had the pattern and the string swapped.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `d+` use 
`[2-9]+`

example:

`re.search("[2-9]+","abc123")`
would give 23 and will ignore 1.